# Trying to Figure Out Where A Mysterious Strong Reference is Coming From

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

OK. I have been reading the excellent "Advanced Swift" book by the objc crew. It's pretty much awesome (but a tough read). It has got me reevaluating the way I've done things in Swift for the last 4 years. I won't link it here, because I don't want this question flagged as spam.

One thing that I'm doing is building up a toolbox of good general-purpose utilities (or rewriting the ones I already have).

One of these tools is a basic GCD Timer.

In the playground that I'll attach, is a basic timer class, along with a testing class and a couple of test implementations.

In one of them, I register a delegate, and the other, I do not. This makes a difference in whether or not the deinit is called on the main test instance.

It looks like the GCD timer hangs onto a strong reference to the delegate, even when I explicitly remove that reference.

As you will see, even when the timer is completely deallocated (its deinit is called), it retains a strong reference to its delegate object (so the main deinit is never called).

Line 257 is interesting. If you comment that out, then the timer keeps firing, even though it has been dereferenced. I can understand that, as I assume that the GCD timer retains a strong reference to its eventHandler. I might be able to avoid that by using an inline closure, instead of referencing an instance method. It doesn't really matter that much, as explicitly calling invalidate() is perfectly fine.

However, it does make me wonder what other strong references are being kept. Changing to an inline closure does not address the main issue; namely, that the main context retains a context, even though it seems to be orphaned.

I'm wondering if someone could explain to me how come the main (`iAmADelegate`) instance is retained. I spent all day yesterday trying to figure it out.

**UPDATE** It looks like this does not happen in an actual app context. [Here is a very basic applet that demonstrates the same tests in the context of an iOS app](https://github.com/LittleGreenViper/BasicGCDTimerDemo).

For the record, here is the console for what I get. If you run the playground, you should get the same:

```
** Test With Delegate
main init
main creating a new timer
timer init
timer changing the delegate from nil to Optional(__lldb_expr_21.EventClass)
timer resume
timer create GCD object
main callback count: 0
main callback count: 1
main callback count: 2
main callback count: 3
main callback count: 4
main deleting the timer
timer invalidate
main callback count: 5
timer changing the delegate from Optional(__lldb_expr_21.EventClass) to nil
timer deinit
** Done

** Test Without Delegate
main init
main creating a new timer
timer init
timer resume
timer create GCD object
main deleting the timer
timer invalidate
timer deinit
** Done
main deinit
```

And here is the playground:

```
import Foundation

/* ################################################################## */
/**
 This is the basic callback protocol for the general-purpose GCD timer class. It has one simple required method.
 */
public protocol BasicGCDTimerDelegate: class {
    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     Called periodically, as the GCDTimer repeats (or fires once).

     - parameter inTimer: The BasicGCDTimer instance that is invoking the callback.
     */
    func timerCallback(_ inTimer: BasicGCDTimer)
}

/* ################################################################## */
/**
 This is a general-purpose GCD timer class.

 It requires that an owning instance register a delegate to receive callbacks.
 */
public class BasicGCDTimer {
    /* ############################################################## */
    // MARK: - Private Enums
    /* ############################################################## */
    /// This is used to hold state flags for internal use.
    private enum _State {
        /// The timer is currently invalid.
        case _invalid
        /// The timer is currently paused.
        case _suspended
        /// The timer is firing.
        case _running
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    // MARK: - Private Instance Properties
    /* ############################################################## */
    /// This holds our current run state.
    private var _state: _State = ._invalid
    /// This holds a Boolean that is true, if we are to only fire once (default is false, which means we repeat).
    private var _onlyFireOnce: Bool = false
    /// This contains the actual dispatch timer object instance.
    private var _timerVar: DispatchSourceTimer!
    /// This is the contained delegate instance
    private weak var _delegate: BasicGCDTimerDelegate?

    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     This dynamically initialized calculated property will return (or create and return) a basic GCD timer that (probably) repeats.

     It uses the current queue.
     */
    private var _timer: DispatchSourceTimer! {
        if nil == _timerVar {   // If we don't already have a timer, we create one. Otherwise, we simply return the already-instantiated object.
            print("timer create GCD object")
            _timerVar = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()                                    // We make a generic, default timer source. No frou-frou.
            let leeway = DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(leewayInMilliseconds)            // If they have provided a leeway, we apply it here. We assume milliseconds.
            _timerVar.setEventHandler(handler: _eventHandler)                               // We reference our own internal event handler.
            _timerVar.schedule(deadline: .now() + timeIntervalInSeconds,                    // The number of seconds each iteration of the timer will take.
                               repeating: (_onlyFireOnce ? 0 : timeIntervalInSeconds),      // If we are repeating (default), we add our duration as the repeating time. Otherwise (only fire once), we set 0.
                               leeway: leeway)                                              // Add any leeway we specified.
        }

        return _timerVar
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    // MARK: - Private Instance Methods
    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     This is our internal event handler that is called directly from the timer.
     */
    private func _eventHandler() {
        delegate?.timerCallback(self)   // Assuming that we have a delegate, we call its handler method.

        if _onlyFireOnce {  // If we are set to only fire once, we nuke from orbit.
            invalidate()
        }
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    // MARK: - Public Instance Properties
    /* ############################################################## */
    /// This is the time between fires, in seconds.
    public var timeIntervalInSeconds: TimeInterval = 0
    /// This is how much "leeway" we give the timer, in milliseconds.
    public var leewayInMilliseconds: Int = 0

    /* ############################################################## */
    // MARK: - Public Calculated Properties
    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     - returns: true, if the timer is invalid. READ ONLY
     */
    public var isInvalid: Bool {
        return ._invalid == _state
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     - returns: true, if the timer is currently running. READ ONLY
     */
    public var isRunning: Bool {
        return ._running == _state
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     - returns: true, if the timer will only fire one time (will return false after that one fire). READ ONLY
     */
    public var isOnlyFiringOnce: Bool {
        return _onlyFireOnce
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     - returns: the delegate object. READ/WRITE
     */
    public var delegate: BasicGCDTimerDelegate? {
        get {
            return _delegate
        }

        set {
            if _delegate !== newValue {
                print("timer changing the delegate from \(String(describing: delegate)) to \(String(describing: newValue))")
                _delegate = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    // MARK: - Deinitializer
    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     We have to carefully dismantle this, as we can end up with crashes if we don't clean up properly.
     */
    deinit {
        print("timer deinit")
        self.invalidate()
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    // MARK: - Public Methods
    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     Default constructor

     - parameter timeIntervalInSeconds: The time (in seconds) between fires.
     - parameter leewayInMilliseconds: Any leeway. This is optional, and default is zero (0).
     - parameter delegate: Our delegate, for callbacks. Optional. Default is nil.
     - parameter onlyFireOnce: If true, then this will only fire one time, as opposed to repeat. Optional. Default is false.
     */
    public init(timeIntervalInSeconds inTimeIntervalInSeconds: TimeInterval,
                leewayInMilliseconds inLeewayInMilliseconds: Int = 0,
                delegate inDelegate: BasicGCDTimerDelegate? = nil,
                onlyFireOnce inOnlyFireOnce: Bool = false) {
        print("timer init")
        self.timeIntervalInSeconds = inTimeIntervalInSeconds
        self.leewayInMilliseconds = inLeewayInMilliseconds
        self.delegate = inDelegate
        self._onlyFireOnce = inOnlyFireOnce
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     If the timer is not currently running, we resume. If running, nothing happens.
     */
    public func resume() {
        if ._running != self._state {
            print("timer resume")
            self._state = ._running
            self._timer.resume()    // Remember that this could create a timer on the spot.
        }
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     If the timer is currently running, we suspend. If not running, nothing happens.
     */
    public func pause() {
        if ._running == self._state {
            print("timer suspend")
            self._state = ._suspended
            self._timer.suspend()
        }
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     This completely nukes the timer. It resets the entire object to default.
     */
    public func invalidate() {
        if ._invalid != _state, nil != _timerVar {
            print("timer invalidate")
            delegate = nil
            _timerVar.setEventHandler(handler: nil)

            _timerVar.cancel()
            if ._suspended == _state {  // If we were suspended, then we need to call resume one more time.
                print("timer one for the road")
                _timerVar.resume()
            }

            _onlyFireOnce = false
            timeIntervalInSeconds = 0
            leewayInMilliseconds = 0
            _state = ._invalid
            _timerVar = nil
        }
    }
}

// Testing class.
class EventClass: BasicGCDTimerDelegate {
    var instanceCount: Int = 0  // How many times we've been called.
    var timer: BasicGCDTimer?   // Our timer object.
    let iAmADelegate: Bool

    // Just prints the count.
    func timerCallback(_ inTimer: BasicGCDTimer) {
        print("main callback count: \(instanceCount)")
        instanceCount += 1
    }

    // Set the parameter to false to remove the delegate registration.
    init(registerAsADelegate inRegisterAsADelegate: Bool = true) {
        print("main init")
        iAmADelegate = inRegisterAsADelegate
        isRunning = true
    }

    // This won't get called if we register as a delegate.
    deinit {
        print("main deinit")
        timer = nil
        isRunning = false
    }

    // This will create and initialize a new timer, if we don't have one. If we turn it off, it will destroy the timer.
    var isRunning: Bool {
        get {
            return nil != timer
        }

        set {
            if !isRunning && newValue {
                print("main creating a new timer")
                timer = BasicGCDTimer(timeIntervalInSeconds: 1.0, leewayInMilliseconds: 200, delegate: iAmADelegate ? self : nil)
                timer?.resume()
            } else if isRunning && !newValue {
                print("main deleting the timer")

                // MARK: - MYSTERY SPOT
                timer?.invalidate()  // If you comment out this line, the timer will keep firing, even though we dereference it.
                // MARK: -

                timer = nil
            }
        }
    }
}

// We instantiate an instance of the test, register it as a delegate, then wait six seconds. We will see updates.
print("** Test With Delegate")   // We will not get a deinit after this one.
let iAmADelegate: EventClass = EventClass()

// We create a timer, then wait six seconds. After that, we stop/delete the timer, and create a new one, without a delegate.
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 6) {
    iAmADelegate.isRunning = false
    print("** Done")   // We will not get a deinit after this one.
    print("\n** Test Without Delegate")
    // Do it again, but this time, don't register as a delegate (it will be quiet).
    let iAmNotADelegate: EventClass = EventClass(registerAsADelegate: false)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 6) {
        iAmNotADelegate.isRunning = false
        print("** Done")   // We will get a deinit after this one.
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a playground make a tiny demo app. You reference ivars  in blocks which implicitly retain self - compiler should generate warnings inside an app, and will ask you to add self. May help you to see problem.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, playgrounds are difficult to debug.

Comment: Yeah...the test project isn't flagging any issues, but I don't have it set up the way I usually do (yet). I usually run -wall. Also, I forgot. I need to pump the event queue in tests (I'm using Unit Tests -I'll try an app, instead).

Comment: Regarding the Mystery Spot: If you don't invalidate the timer, the runloop will keep a strong reference and therefore the timer won't get released even when you set your reference to nil. From the Timer-class docs (invalidate() method): _The run loop then removes the timer (and the strong reference it had to the timer), either just before the invalidate() method returns or at some later point._

Comment: Huh. I just did what @David H said to do, and it works for both (with[out] delegate).

Looks like I can't trust playgrounds to properly test this kind of stuff, which is probably OK.

I'll probably make the test app available in GH.

Comment: OK. [Here Is A Simple App Test Demo](https://github.com/LittleGreenViper/BasicGCDTimerDemo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is one that could not have been predicted without actually creating a project.

It seems that the Playground Swift engine deals with reference-counting and scope differently from the app engine. It hangs onto things longer. I could probably get it to behave correctly by wrapping the whole thing in another scope that gets dereferenced.

Unfortunately, the "Mystery Spot" answer doesn't apply here, as that's for the higher-level Timer method. This is a lower-level GCD timed task.